# I used body parser but its returning { } while using Post using Postman (JSON data)

Tags: node.js, express

In Controller/post.js

```
  exports.createPost = (req,res)=>{
  const post = new Post(req.body);
  console.log("Creating Post:",req.body); };
```

In app.js , I have installed body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And i am posting a POST request from POSTMAN 
[Postman Scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soKZw.png)

[Screenshot 2 - Content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCcLq.png)

I should have got body parsed and should have got req.body as my output.
But my output comes as
   Creating Post: {}
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNUnD.png)

Why this is happening ?

Comment: While request from Postman, do you have tried setting "Content-Type: application/json" ?

Comment: Yes , you can check screenshot 2 : if its correct or not

Comment: It's not, check the second option: Content-Type: application/json and then try again.

Comment: While taking screenshot , by mistake 3rd option got selected.. But even after selecting content type as JSON , I got same result

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need to 
replace

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

with

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// make sure the end-points are defined below.
```

Comment: Its not coming :( :(

Comment: Can you post the complete code? So that I can know, how your app.js and post.js is linked.

Answer (score 0):

So after finding a lot , I saw that POSTMAN is sending auto generated Headers.And you cant even disable them. So I have installed Insomnia, And it works superb.